# New Line in SPAN

Tags: html, css, angular, line

I am returning below sample value from API and binding it in span element.What I am trying to achieve is to Keep every **Unit** in separate new line/

```
"Unit1-Employee1 , Unit2- Employee 2, Unit3- Employee 3,Employee 4"
```

I have tried to append **\n**  before every Unit in API  and bind it to span but it is not starting in new line.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
const string = "Unit1-Employee1 , Unit2- Employee 2, Unit3- Employee 3,Employee 4";
const array = string.split(",");
```

In HTML:

```
<span *ngFor="let data of array">
  {{data}} <br>
</span>
```

Demo Link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ylntb

Answer (score 1):

Push these units in an array and iterate over these items and display each item in span and put a `<br>` after each `<span>`. Like shown below:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of arr">
  {{item}} <br>
</span>
```

**Working Demo** : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qek65h)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you will be storing each elements in an array.
Now, iterate through the array as follows.

```
<span *ngFor="let item of items" style="display:block">
 {{item}}
</span>
```

Or, Simply put it inside div

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item}}
</div>
```